# Font Awesome Printing Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, font-awesome

I'm developing and testing a Joomla 3 website that is using Font Awesome version 4.03 (built into JA Purity III template). 
Using Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7
I did a test print of the site and in print preview all of the FA fonts are missing. If I send the webpage to the printer I end up with odd streak like marks, the center of every letter "M" is offset upwards and all the font awesome icons are missing.
I also checked the Font Awesome website and if I try to print out the icons list it is blank as well. 
Any ideas on what could be causing this or how I can further troubleshoot it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font awesome is based on the fonts in the font directory. To be true its hard to print better use screenshots and then print them.